# fiddler and java ws problem

Tags: java, fiddler

```
Properties systemProps = System.getProperties();
//systemProps.put("proxySet", "true");
systemProps.put("proxyHost", "127.0.0.1");
systemProps.put("proxyPort", "8888");
```

When I open fiddler I can't see anything.  Must I do something else?  I use fiddler proxy for sending ws request.

Comment: "proxySet" does nothing. Proof: set it to "false". There is not and has never been such a property in the JDK, various books and online references notwithstanding. It came from the long-defunct HotJavaBean, an encapsulated browser, died a death in about 1998.

Answer (score 1):

Try starting the application with startup parameters

```
-DproxyHost=127.0.0.1 -DproxyPort=8888
```

if that helps, it is probable that your code is called too late or maybe not at all.

Comment: thx, i add this as program parameters but fiddler still shows nothing. can i somehow then change end point or something that i will se what i am ending...

Comment: The your fiddler setup is another place to look for errors. I'm not familiar with it, thinking it was just a proxy. http://www.fiddler2.com/Fiddler/help/hookup.asp#Q-LocalTraffic looks promising, though

Comment: Also, ensure you don't have any Filters set that might be hiding the traffic: http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler/help/faq.asp#missingtraffic